# PocketSphinx runtime error in log file

Tags: cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I am working on PocketSphinx. While running it, it shows some error in a log file. I can't understand them; what do they mean? Here are the errors:

```
   { ERROR: "forward.c", line 594: All 2 active states, 36 37, zero at time 1
    ERROR: "baum_welch.c", line 324: male1/eight ignored
        16 0 
    INFO: cmn.c(133): CMN: 1736.53 3228.30 -899.98 2679.72 -1582.93 -1126.47 -1513.65 -335.25 -1766.16 3463.14 2127.38 -979.71 2194.59 
    WARN: "corpus.c", line 1481: Utterance id in the transcription file, 'male1/five', does not match id in the control file, 'five'.
    ERROR: "forward.c", line 594: All 2 active states, 36 37, zero at time 1
    ERROR: "baum_welch.c", line 324: male1/five ignored
    utt>     1                      five  140    0    20 0 
    INFO: cmn.c(133): CMN: -798.98 2317.53 -5785.50 5469.77 -6605.24 -5970.96 -792.98 1046.92 -622.59 -6760.83 -853.49 -653.04 6555.86 
    WARN: "corpus.c", line 1481: Utterance id in the transcription file, 'male1/four', does not match id in the control file, 'four'.
    ERROR: "forward.c", line 594: All 2 active states, 36 37, zero at time 1
    ERROR: "baum_welch.c", line 324: male1/four ignored
    utt>     2                      four   77    0    20 0 
    INFO: cmn.c(133): CMN: 2708.64 -2833.31 4465.99 -2474.95 4256.10 -3710.75 1517.68 -3744.27 217.52 -3049.00 4280.67 3826.02 313.39 
    WARN: "corpus.c", line 1481: Utterance id in the transcription file, 'male1/nine', does not match id in the control file, 'nine'.
    ERROR: "forward.c", line 594: All 2 active states, 36 37, zero at time 1
    ERROR: "baum_welch.c", line 324: male1/nine ignored
    utt>     3                      nine  117    0    20 0 
    INFO: cmn.c(133): CMN: 4367.13 534.72 1667.75 -2840.18 2580.05 2861.98 2442.50 4493.30 2685.47 2841.25 -2529.57 -2752.00 -1507.38 
    WARN: "corpus.c", line 1481: Utterance id in the transcription file, 'male1/one', does not match id in the control file, 'one'.
    ERROR: "forward.c", line 594: All 2 active states, 36 37, zero at time 1
    ERROR: "baum_welch.c", line 324: male1/one ignored
    utt>     4                       one  110    0    20 0 
    INFO: cmn.c(133): CMN: -3718.15 -127.92 -3321.35 -1311.25 -1532.32 -1533.98 3016.80 -430.44 -1817.81 -1350.10 -1727.87 -2011.16 2224.16 
    WARN: "corpus.c", line 1481: Utterance id in the transcription file, 'male1/seven', does not match id in the control file, 'seven'.
    ERROR: "forward.c", line 594: All 2 active states, 36 37, zero at time 1
    ERROR: "baum_welch.c", line 324: male1/seven ignored
    utt>     5                     seven  122    0    28 0 
    INFO: cmn.c(133): CMN: -5035.38 -5103.44 -3878.29 -5700.23 -5596.67 -5654.61 -4015.24 -98.45 -5181.37 1043.58 54.60 5486.20 5289.32 
    WARN: "corpus.c", line 1481: Utterance id in the transcription file, 'male1/six', does not match id in the control file, 'six'.
    ERROR: "forward.c", line 594: All 2 active states, 36 37, zero at time 1
    ERROR: "baum_welch.c", line 324: male1/six ignored
    utt>     6                       six   91    0    24 0 
    INFO: cmn.c(133): CMN: -387.01 -1261.31 -2724.07 -890.98 2247.32 3631.96 1860.44 -129.39 2424.72 4224.40 -2736.33 2732.74 -2814.56 
    WARN: "corpus.c", line 1481: Utterance id in the transcription file, 'male1/ten', does not match id in the control file, 'ten'.
    ERROR: "forward.c", line 594: All 2 active states, 36 37, zero at time 1
    ERROR: "baum_welch.c", line 324: male1/ten ignored
    utt>     7                       ten  108    0    20 0 
    INFO: cmn.c(133): CMN: -1375.65 -3763.73 159.53 -2580.91 3806.55 -3326.88 -3192.88 2013.50 -3951.76 -2264.89 -3697.22 330.14 -4154.19 
    WARN: "corpus.c", line 1481: Utterance id in the transcription file, 'male1/three', does not match id in the control file, 'three'.
    ERROR: "forward.c", line 594: All 2 active states, 36 37, zero at time 1
    ERROR: "baum_welch.c", line 324: male1/three ignored
    utt>     8                     three  123    0    20 0 
    INFO: cmn.c(133): CMN: -660.11 -3743.96 697.49 242.08 -1517.09 -1629.75 6370.77 563.54 5316.62 2227.69 221.45 -547.87 -5667.59 
    WARN: "corpus.c", line 1481: Utterance id in the transcription file, 'male1/two', does not match id in the control file, 'two'.
    ERROR: "forward.c", line 594: All 2 active states, 36 37, zero at time 1
    ERROR: "baum_welch.c", line 324: male1/two ignored
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means input audio has wrong format. It has to be 16khz 16bit mono PCM WAV file.

Comment: Thank you, but the input audio file format is ok , I can't understand the error . Is there any other reason for creating this error?

Comment: Log says the audio format is wrong. You need to double-check yourself, people often make mistakes.

Comment: Here is a sample file for number 1 to 10. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jz9FZiLWVKlG6sEMlQE2dOoGiqjGcpnn/view?usp=sharing

It will be very helpful if you take a look to this file. Thank you very much.

Comment: Another reason is might be that you compiled sphinxbase with fixed point.

Comment: Thanks , but how can i solve this . I am new in this area.